# How to install public key in host windows server 2012

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012, openssh, sftp

My user from another server gave his public key to me and asked me to install this public key into my server so he can connect to my server. Did some research and I have to create a directory called `.ssh` and paste my user public key in a Notepad and save this text file into the `.ssh` directory. My question is does my research correct if so where and how I create this `.ssh` directory and the key file, is it in text file format? Do I have to pass any information like my key to the user? I’m using Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92378/discussion-on-question-by-xchaax-how-to-install-public-key-in-host-windows-serve).

Answer (score 12):

- The public key must go into `authorized_keys` file (not just to *some* text file) in the `.ssh` subfolder of user's home directory.
- The public key entry must have a correct format like:

  ```
    ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAIEAir2cIHsAFg8QzLF6Yb... some optional comment
  ```
- The `authorized_keys` file must use *nix line endings, what Notepad cannot do (so make sure your SFTP/FTP client uses ASCII transfer mode to convert the line endings)
- The `.ssh` folder needs to have `700` permissions and the `authorized_keys` needs to have `600` permissions.

There are zillions of guides on the Internet that cover the above.
For example see my guide to [Setting up SSH public key authentication in OpenSSH](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_public_key#configure_openssh).

---

If the user is already a user on your server (has password [or other] authentication working), he/she can setup the public key on his/her own.

- On *nix machines (or others that have OpenSSH available, what [may include Windows](https://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875)), you can use [`ssh-copy-id` script](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/openssh-client/ssh-copy-id.1.en.html).
- On Windows machines, you can use (my) WinSCP, with its [*Install Public Key into Server* function](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_authentication#private_key).

See also my answer to [Setting up public key authentication to Linux server from Windows (ppk private key)](https://serverfault.com/q/909823/168875).

---

You should provide your user a copy of the server's public host key, so that the user can verify it, when connecting for the first time (it's a separate from the authentication, what the rest of the question is about). *Though many users just blindly accept the host key.*

Comment: Does it matter what directory for .ssh folder ? If does, what directory is home directory? And what is the format for authorized_keys file ?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: More generally, the public key must go in whatever file is specified as `AuthorizedKeysFile` in `sshd_config`, which _by default_ is `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: It's a bit of a sloppy hack, but on new machines I generally run a 'ssh-keygen' to create the `~/.ssh/` directory in the proper place with the proper permissions, and then copy keys into the authorized_keys file.